# django login redirects to "/undefined"

Tags: django

Using django, I have a simple login form :

login.html :

```
<form id="" method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}" class="form" role="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    <div class="pull-right">
        <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="submit"></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', MainView.as_view(), name='main'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

And in `settings.py`, the following parameter :

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'main'
```

When I log in as a user, I get redirected multiple times and end up at a '/undefined' url, but the login does work :

```
[19/Jul/2019 13:09:53] "GET /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 956
# CLICK ON THE SUBMIT BUTTON
[19/Jul/2019 13:09:54] "POST /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[19/Jul/2019 13:09:54] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2496
Not Found: /undefined
[19/Jul/2019 13:09:54] "GET /undefined HTTP/1.1" 404 2189
```

What could cause the last redirection ? '/' should be the ending url.

EDIT : 
If I use the direct `http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/` URL to login, I don't get redirected to `/undefined` :

```
[19/Jul/2019 13:57:51] "GET /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 953
[19/Jul/2019 13:57:55] "POST /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[19/Jul/2019 13:57:55] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2496
```

Comment: does this occur after submitting the form?

Comment: yes it happens when I press the submit buttons, also the login does work, only the redirection fails.

Comment: The logs show that you were redirected to `/`: `[19/Jul/2019 13:09:54] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2496`. So I would look at `MainView` to see why it is redirecting you to `/undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

try

`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/main/'`

instead of

`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'main'`

in settings.py and let me know

Comment: I get the error `Not Found: /main/
[19/Jul/2019 13:34:01] "GET /main/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2177`, I did also try with juste `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'`

Comment: `LOGIN_URL = '/login/'` try this

Comment: the LOGIN_URL parameter didn't seem to have changed anything

Comment: Goto this path:  `your_venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py` in that file goto line 69 and change `redirect_to = 'url_you_want_to_redirect_after_login'`

Answer (score 0):

I have a `login_user` view:

```
def login_user(request):
    form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    if form.is_valid():
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return render(request, 'login.html', context)
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('base')
        else:
            return render(request,
                          'login.html',
                          {'error_message': 'Invalid login'}
                          )
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html', context)
```

with `action="{% url '<app_name>:login_user'%}"` in `login.html`

and `base` is the main template.

Then in `urls`:

```
url(r'^login_user/$', views.login_user, name='login_user'),
```

Comment: I was hopping I didn't need to create the view, especially since the login does work but with a bad redirection. But if I can't succeed that is probably what I will do

Comment: I think creating the view is actually the proper way of doing it, because afterwards you will have greater control over the user logging.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating my own loginclass, although I don't know which mecanism was problematic in the first place

```
class MyLoginView(LoginView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        login(self.request, form.get_user())
        messages.add_message(self.request, messages.SUCCESS,
                                    'Welcome.')
        data = {
        'success_url': self.get_success_url()
        }
        return JsonResponse(data)
```